# Is there a shortest path algorithm with a threshold distance, beyond which it does not try to compute?

Tags: graph-theory, shortest-path

I want to calculate the shortest path between all pairs of N nodes (each with about 3 directed edges). The important nuance is that if the distance is greater than some threshold (T), I no longer care about it (D_ij>T = ∞ as far as I'm concerned).

So, once I know for sure that the distance from i to j is greater than the threshold I no longer need to keep looking for the exact value, just to know that it's greater than the threshold.

Is there already a shortest path algorithm that incorporates such threshold information to make the process more efficient?

Note that for all cases in which D_ij < T I do care about the exact value of D.

Comment: If you are satisfied with the answer to your question, please mark it as answered. Otherwise, please give feedback or refine your question to see if someone else can answer it. Or possibly try to get it moved to math.stackexchange to get some more eyes on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want distances between all pairs of nodes, look at the Floyd-Warshall algorithm.

[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floyd–Warshall_algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floyd%E2%80%93Warshall_algorithm)

How about running the FW algorithm and just truncating the results to T after its done (running time O(N^3) followed by truncation)?

If you're graph is huge (N large), then, for 3 edges per node, it's quite sparse. In such a case, a better choice would be to perform Dijkstra's method for each possible starting vertex, in which case you could abort the method as soon as the cumulative distance of the processed nodes exceed T.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm

---

As an alternative, switch from solving your problem heuristically to instead solving the linear program (LP) equivalent to the shortest path problem, see e.g. [How to formulate LP for shortest path problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33997866/how-to-formulate-lp-for-shortest-path-problems).

In this context, your problem is just a general shortest path problem (one LP for each node pair), but with an additional constraint:

```
objective function cost <= T  (+)
```

Given that there exists directed edges from each node, the corresponding LP for the original problem---for each node pair---will always be feasible. Hence, in your case, if the LP for a certain node pair is infeasible, it means that no path can be found that fulfils your additional constraint (+). Subsequently, the shortest path for that pair, say D_ij, is larger than T, i.e., D_ij>T.

Solving LP:s related to shortest path problems can generally be really fast (given a good LP solver), also for finding infeasibility. Perhaps this is can be an alternative for you, w.r.t. the heuristic approach.

Comment: Thanks. I will explore both truncating Dijkstra's method and the LP solution, seeing what performs better. N=100000 and performance is critical (running hundreds of thousands of times, each time with a different set of weights).

Comment: Your welcome. I'm quite interested in the outcome, so if you wouldn't mind, please add a comment (or even an answer if you manage to rigorously answer your own question) with your findings. Good luck!

Comment: @Shimi Another comment: when using the LP approach, note that many LP solvers allow for 'warm-starting' of the Simplex method, in the sense that a basic feasible solution (BFS), perhaps optimal in some variation of a problem, can be used as a good (even non-optimal) initial BFS in a related problem. I the problems are related in terms of added constraints, then by choosing the dual simplex method you can assure feasibility of using a BFS from one problem in another (as an additional constraint in the primal is just another variable in the dual). Could possibly be applied in your case of study.

Comment: I did end up using the truncated Dijkstra method for a while, but it was too slow (at least my own attempts at an implementation) so I completely re-formulated my problem without using graph theory at all.